# A Dual Ajax ListBox

Tags: ajax, listbox

Do you guys know of any .net controls with 2 listboxes that can move items from left to right and vice versa?! 
Like a dual listbox type of thing.
I have already looked at http://ajaxlistbox.codeplex.com/ it seems to be pretty sweet.

just want to know any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

Make two ListBoxes, the first shows all available item, the second shows what the user chooses.  You also need a TextBox to hold a copy of the chosen items, since it is not possible to retrieve ListBox items in C# if they were added via javascript.  Make the TextBox hidden, so the user cannot accidentally mess up the items.

Click an item in the first listbox and it appears in the second "chosen" listbox.  Click on chosen item in the second list and it disappears.  You could alter this so items are removed from the first list after being chosen.

I call AddJavascript from my Page_Load method.

ListBoxFilteredProfiles is my first TextBox, ListBoxSelectedProfiles is the second.

```
    private     void    AddJavascript()
    {
        // This javascript function adds the item selected in one listbox to another listbox.
        // Duplicates are not allowed, items are inserted in alphabetical order.

        string  OnChangeProfileListBoxJavascript   = 

@"<script language=JavaScript>
<!--
function OnChangeSelectedProfiles()
{ 
  var Target = document.getElementById('" + ListBoxSelectedProfiles.ID + @"');  
  var Source = document.getElementById('" + ListBoxFilteredProfiles.ID + @"'); 
  var TB = document.getElementById('"     + TextBoxProfiles        .ID + @"'); 
  if ((Source != null)  &&  (Target != null)) {
    var newOption = new Option();  // a new ListItem
    newOption.text  = Source.options[ Source.options.selectedIndex ].text;
    newOption.value = Source.options[ Source.options.selectedIndex ].value;

    var jj = 0;

    for( jj = 0;  jj < Target.options.length;  ++jj )  { 
      if ( newOption.text == Target.options[ jj ].text )  { return true; } // don't add if already in the list
      if ( newOption.text  < Target.options[ jj ].text )  { break; }       // add the new item at this position
    }

    for( var kk = Target.options.length;  kk > jj;  --kk )  {  // bump the remaining list items up one position
      var bumpItem = new Option();
      bumpItem.text  = Target.options[ kk-1 ].text;  // copy the preceding item
      bumpItem.value = Target.options[ kk-1 ].value;
      Target.options[ kk ] = bumpItem;
    }

    Target.options[ jj ] = newOption;  // Append the item in Target
    if (TB != null) {
      // Copy all the selected profiles into the hidden textbox.  The C# codebehind gets the selections from the textbox because listbox values added via javascript are not accessible.
      TB.value = '';
      for( var jj= 0;  jj < Target.options.length;  ++jj )  { TB.value = TB.value + Target.options[ jj ].value + '\n'; }
    }
  }
}
// -->
</script> ";


        // This javascript function removes an item from a listbox.
        string  OnChangeRemoveListBoxItemJavascript   = 
@"<script language=JavaScript>
<!--
function OnChangeRemoveProfile()
{ 
  var Target = document.getElementById('" + ListBoxSelectedProfiles.ID + @"');  
  var TB = document.getElementById('"     + TextBoxProfiles.ID         + @"'); 
  Target.remove( Target.options.selectedIndex );
  TB.value = '';
  // Copy all the selected profiles into the hidden textbox.  The C# codebehind gets the selections from the textbox because listbox values added via javascript are not accessible.
  for( var jj= 0;  jj < Target.options.length;  ++jj )  { TB.value = TB.value + Target.options[ jj ].value + '\n'; }
}
// -->
</script> ";


        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( typeof(Page),  "OnChangeSelectedProfiles",  OnChangeProfileListBoxJavascript ); 
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( typeof(Page),  "OnChangeRemoveProfile",     OnChangeRemoveListBoxItemJavascript ); 

        ListBoxFilteredProfiles.Attributes.Add("onchange", "OnChangeSelectedProfiles()" ); 
        ListBoxSelectedProfiles.Attributes.Add("onchange", "OnChangeRemoveProfile()" ); 
    }
```